# exception.lineNumber returns "undefined" in google chrome and internet explorer

Tags: javascript, exception, cross-browser, line-numbers

I need to get fileName, Message, LineNumber etc from a javascript exception. I tried the following code.

```
try {
  alertt("dddd");
} catch (e) {
  console.log("ExceptionType: "+ e.name);
  console.log("Message: "+ e.message);
  console.log("Line No: "+ e.lineNumber);
}
```

I got the following result in Mozilla Firefox

> **ExceptionType:** ReferenceError
>   **Message:** alertt is not defined
>   **Line No:** 4

But the same code gave the following result in Google Chrome, Internet Explorer

> **ExceptionType:** ReferenceError
>   **Message:** alertt is not defined
>   **Line No:** undefined

It is not giving the Line Number. How to solve this issue? Is there any another method for getting Line number?

I tried **e.stack** It returns the stack trace as string.
It gave me the following output in Google Chrome

```
 ReferenceError: alertt is not defined
    at message (http://localhost/ems-test/js/test.js:4:4)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost/ems-test/js/test.js:14:2)
    at c (http://localhost/ems-test/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4:26036)
    at Object.p.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://localhost/ems-test/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4:26840)
    at Function.x.extend.ready (http://localhost/ems-test/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4:3305)
    at HTMLDocument.q (http://localhost/ems-test/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4:717)
```

and firefox gave this result

```
message@http://localhost/ems-test/js/test.js:4
@http://localhost/ems-test/js/test.js:14
x.Callbacks/c@http://localhost/ems-test/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
x.Callbacks/p.fireWith@http://localhost/ems-test/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
.ready@http://localhost/ems-test/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
q@http://localhost/ems-test/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
```

Both are string type result. Not an object. So it needs to extract the line number from this huge string. But the problem is both result are not same. One shows the line number in first line and another one shows it in second line. So it will be difficult to extract line number from this huge string.

Is there any method to get the stack trace as an object?

Comment: The Error object API is not standardized.

Comment: is there any other method for getting line number?

Comment: I don't know of any way to do it in Internet Explorer or Chrome/Safari, but maybe somebody does.

Comment: Maybe stack contains the line number: e.stack

Comment: look into this stacktrace lib https://github.com/eriwen/javascript-stacktrace

Comment: @Point—the API is [stanardised](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.11) (i.e. error objects and their properties are included in the standard), but it may be extended (as may pretty much any native object) by implementations provided such extensions don't contravene ECMA-262.

Comment: If you are executing from console line number may seem ambiguous. Line number is usually of script/html containing the code and not injected script. The html & script error/line numbering is standardised but for injected script that depends on the browser implementation.

Comment: @HMR I tried e.stack. But it is not working in IE. Do you know how to get stack trace in IE?

Comment: @RobG sorry yes I meant that beyond the (pretty minimal) standard it's all over the place between browsers.

Comment: @Sajith e.stack is Supported in Internet Explorer 10

Comment: The problem is not necessarily the API.  In javascript, you can throw *anything*. `try { throw function(){ alert("woo!");}; } catch(e) {e();}`

Comment: @JayC Do you know how to get line number from this exception in chrome and IE?

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onerror = function (msg, url, line) {
   alert("Message : " + msg );
   alert("url : " + url );
   alert("Line number : " + line );
}
```

Hope this might help you.
check on this link: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cgi-bin/practice.cgi?file=javascript_40

Comment: This one I already done. My requirement is to get this in try...catch.

Comment: While using window.onerror(), we will get the line number. But how to get it while using try{}catch{}?

Comment: This one works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have IE on my machine, so I can't speak for that; but in Chrome, you might be able to get what you need by looking at the e.stack property and parsing it out. You can see the options available to you if you do a console.dir(e) within your catch block.